# Общение ботов в Telegram

Tags: telegram

Можно ли с помощью API ботов в Telegram слать сообщения от одного бота другому боту? Если да, то как?

Comment: В личку напрямую нельзя. Но можно организовать "переговоры" ботов через канал.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

На самом деле, начиная с 21 ноября 2016 года боты в Telegram могут «общаться» между собой через канал. Дело в том, что начиная с этой даты, боты смогли видеть сообщения из каналов, любые, даже от других ботов.

Нижеследующий пример на питоне демонстрирует такое взаимодействие — взаимные приветствия с интервалом не чаще раза в секунду.

```py
# Демонстрационный однопоточный бот
bot = telebot.TeleBot(sys.argv[1], threaded=False)

# Разрешаем получение обновлений из каналов
bot.get_updates(allowed_updates=["channel_post"])

# Логин бота для вывода
name = bot.get_me().username

@bot.channel_post_handler()
def hello(msg):
    bot.reply_to(msg, "Привет, я @" + name)
    time.sleep(1)

bot.polling()
```

Прежде чем начать выполнять опросы следует вызвать метод **getUpdates** с параметром **allowed_updates**, разрешающим получение обновлений в каналах. Сами обновления нам пока не важны — с ними пусть разберётся библиотека pyTelegramBotAPI.

Пример работы скрипта, если одновременно запустить два его экземпляра в консоли.

[image: Снимок экрана с тестовым каналом]

Answer (score 1):

С помощью API этого сделать нельзя:

> **Why doesn't my bot see messages from other bots?**
>   Bots talking to each other could potentially get stuck in unwelcome loops. To avoid this,
>   we decided that bots will not be able to see messages from other bots
>   regardless of mode.

https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#why-doesn-39t-my-bot-see-messages-from-other-bots

Comment: Извиняюсь за некропост, но я чего-то недопонимаю, или это и вправду можно сделать с помощью API? Я добавил двух ботов в канал (сделав их админами), и оба **могут** читать сообщения друг друга.