# Telegram бот слушающий другого бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Есть задача написать телеграм бота, который должен слушать сообщения другого стороннего телеграм бота и по результатам парсинга сообщения выполнять какие-то действия на сервере.
Посодействуйте примером, как это можно реализовать.
Пока наткнулся в интернетах на то, что бот не может сооздавать чат с другим ботом, так ли это?

Comment: Такой вариант не подходит? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/639819/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-telegram

Comment: Вряд ли сторонний бот будет на это расчитан. Если вы хотите эксплуатировать чужого бота, вам следует использовать протокол MtProto, чтобы представиться обычным пользователем. Можно написать скрипт для telegram-cli.

Comment: Так и сделал, поднял cli, который слушает бота, все что принято попадает в lua скрипт и там обрабатывается.

Comment: Не хотите ответить на свой вопрос самостоятельно и описать своё решение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, бот не может писать "стороннему" боту.
Бот может писать боту только в случае если ты владелец ботов, и произвёл с ними определённые манипуляции.
[image: Группа с участниками типа Bot]
Ты можешь создать группу либо канал и добавить (пригласить) в неё два и, или более ботов.
В этом случае боты будут слышать друг друга, при условии что у обоих включено BotFather=>Bot=>Settings=>Group Privacy => Privacy mode disabled
и
BotFather=>Bot=>Settings=>Allow Groups? => Groups are currently enabled

И ещё есть ограничение у Telegram, бот не может отправить более 30 сообщений в секунду.
Высоко нагруженного канала создать не удастся.

Comment: В группе не пашут по вашей инструкции.

Comment: Такой настройки вообще нет в bot father

Comment: это работало ранее, боты могли видеть сообщения других ботов, но чтобы они не создавали зацикленность это полностью убрали.

Answer (score 2):

Это так, боты не могут писать другим ботам и читать сообщения других ботов.