# telegram bot использовать в качестве ответа на команду ответ другого бота (python)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, inline

Хочу чтобы при вводе команды "/any_command", мой бот делал инлайн запрос типа "@wiki ru moscow" и выдавал первый результат из списка.

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["any_command"])
def any_msg(message):

    inlineQuery = "@wiki ru moscow"

    #что нужно указать в "result"
    result = "???"

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, result)
```

Такое вообще возможно?
Буду благодарен хотя бы за ссылку на метод в оф документации.

Comment: Такое вариант реализовать нельзя. Но боты таки могут взаимодействовать между собой через API телеграма. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/642975/183314

Answer (score 1):

Боты не могут писать другим ботам, а также читать сообщения других ботов.